# How to add eventListener to web-bluetooth API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, web-bluetooth

I want to make a small physical button device to control playing 3 short audios on my web app using web bluetooth API, meaning that click once physical button, it will play the first audio, and click again, it will play the second audio..

Based on what I have read on the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web), I should use the custom characteristic, which require the entire UUID of the device. After that, I put a eventlistener to call a function to play the audio. But I got error message `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`. I don't know why this happens.

Am I missing something? Or my logic is wrong?
Please note that I don't have my physical button yet, so I test bluetooth connection with my iPhone for now, so the function test is just to see any output.

Below is what I have:

```
$("#bluetooth").on("click", function(){
        const controlServiceUUID = '00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'; // Full UUID
        const commandCharacteristicUUID = '00002a0f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'; // [READ]
        const commandCharacteristicUUID2 = '00002a0f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'; // [READ, NOTIFY]

        console.log('Searching Bluetooth Device...');

        navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            acceptAllDevices: true,
            optionalServices: [controlServiceUUID]
        })

        .then(device => {
            console.log("Got device name: ", device.name);
            console.log("id: ", device.id);
            return device.gatt.connect();
        })

        .then(server => {
            // Step 3: Get the Service
            serverInstance = server;
            return server.getPrimaryService(controlServiceUUID);
            console.log("Getting PrimaryService");
        })

        .then(service => {
            service.getCharacteristic(commandCharacteristicUUID);
            console.log("Getting Characteristic");
        })

        .then(characteristic => {
            // 0x01,3,0x02,0x03,0x01

            characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', test);             
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Something went wrong. " + error);
        });

       function test(event) {
           let commandValue = event.target.value.getUint8(0);
           console.log("Hello");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the Promise to use the characteristic. See below.

`.then(service => {
            console.log("Getting Characteristic");
            return service.getCharacteristic(commandCharacteristicUUID);
        })`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will test it later tonight. Another question from me, what I have seen examples about web bluetooth API, most people do smart phone to control hardware such as light. I want to reverse it, use hardware button to control smart phone to play audio.Is it possible?    Btw, I can recognize you :)

Comment: You'd have to pair your hardware button with your web app with Web Bluetooth and simply "notifies" a BLE characteristic. Then, your web app can simply listener to this characteristic notification changes and play an audio file for instance: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/notifications.html
Note that this require your web app to be launched.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'd love to try it out. and I'm trying to pair the RN-42, but it shows `NetworkError: Unsupported device.`  Not sure what happens. Is it because RN-42 is not BLE device?

Comment: I just look up more physics button with Bluetooth low energy, seems FLIC can do the job! What do you think?

Comment: RN-42 seems to be Bluetooth Classic only (not BLE) indeed.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I read the thread, and it seems like you have solved some bugs :) Basically, I think what I need to do is to make my web app with web bluetooth API and deployed on the custom IFTTT platform and connected to the FLIC. Please correct me if I'm thinking anything wrong, or missing anything.

Comment: Sorry, I have many questions. I need to have more confidence before I purchase a FLIC